# Ajax Json Data in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have built a jQuery Function to pull through a district_id and authority name for a form I have made.

The user clicks search via a postcode and it populates the box with the postcode, However when I go to populate the district_id field, It doesnt seem to load it in. I can get the authority name in, No problem but the district_id nothing!

My jQuery code is as follows :

```
$('.search-district').click(function() {

    var postcode = $(".postcode").val();

    var post_url = "/core/get-district-data/" + postcode;

   $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       url  : post_url,
       success: function(districts)
       {
           $.each(districts, function(district_id,la_name)
           {
               $('.postcode').val(la_name);
               $('#district_id').val(district_id);
           })
       }
   })
});
```

Example jSon Data is as follows :

```
{"district_id":2581,"la_name":"Hartlepool Borough Council"}
```

How do I populate the district id field with the correct district ID? Currently it is populating it with a "1"? When it should be 2581?

**EDIT:** I can also change the jSon data in my PHP if needs be. To remove "district_id" and "la_name" if required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you `each` ? it's a single object ( not an array)

Comment: I guess thats my question, Do I need to each. etc?

Comment: Why do you use `POST` request, if there is no body?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: @Engineer maybe he is querying a webservice which works(should) only with post ....?

Comment: Hi @Engineer I am using a Webservice as Royi Namir pointed out. The data is posted to a method in a controller.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Then webservice is configured in wrong way.

Comment: @Engineer - Care to explain?

Comment: @StuBlackett Write "difference between GET and POST" in google and you'll find the explanations! *Essentially GET is used to retrieve remote data, and POST is used to insert/update remote data*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) with a callback function passes the index as the first parameter.

What you should be doing is this:

```
$.each(districts, function(district_id, district)
{
     $('.postcode').val(district.la_name);
     $('#district_id').val(district.district_id);
})
```

However, if it is only a single object returned just access the properties directly:

```
 $('.postcode').val(districts.la_name);
 $('#district_id').val(districts.district_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you `each` ? it's a single object ( not an array) –

```
 $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       url  : post_url,
       success: function(districts)
       {
            $('.postcode').val(districts.la_name);
            $('#district_id').val(districts.district_id);

       }
   })
```

notice .

you can also use each  in your sample.

but it will be a single iteration `each`. ( it's still ok though).

Also,

please add : `datatype:"json"`